# How to configure RestKit for Core Data persistence?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm desperately trying to get RestKit Core Data configuration right but I must be doing something wrong because when I load objects, they are correctly mapped but never persisted.
I ended up copy/pasting everything from RKTwitterCoreData example and got to the following code, but I still get nothing in my database:

```
- (void)configureRestKit {
    //[[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] setLevel:AFLoggerLevelDebug];
    //[[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];

    // Initialize RestKit
    NSString *serverUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFServerUrl"];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverUrl]];
    objectManager.HTTPClient = [CFHTTPClient sharedClient];

    // Enable Activity Indicator Spinner
    [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

    // Initialize managed object store
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

    // Setup our object mappings
    /**
     Mapping by entity. Here we are configuring a mapping by targetting a Core Data entity with a specific
     name. This allows us to map back Twitter user objects directly onto NSManagedObject instances --
     there is no backing model class!
     */
    RKEntityMapping *eventMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    eventMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"eventId"];
    [eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"eventId", @"title", @"startDate", @"endDate", @"city", @"country"]];

    [...]

    // Update date format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [RKObjectMapping setDefaultDateFormatters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dateFormatter]];

    // Register our mappings with the provider
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:eventMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"events" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    [objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Event class] pathPattern:@"event" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
    [objectManager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Event class] pathPattern:@"event/:eventId" method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

    /**
     Complete Core Data stack initialization
     */
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter4.sqlite"];
    NSError *error;
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption :@YES} error:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

    // Create the managed object contexts
    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
}
```

Comment: How have you defined `eventMapping`? When are you setting the MOC to the `objectManager`?

Comment: I just added eventMapping initialization code above. But what do you mean by "setting the MOC to the objectManager"? It could be what I'm missing.

Comment: It's actually the `managedObjectStore` property of the `objectManager`, not MOC.

Comment: Then yes, it is there, right after the creation of managedObjectStore.

Answer (score 3):

In case you're still looking for an answer, I came across the same problem today in RestKit 0.22.0 and got persistence by manually creating a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and initializing the `RKManagedObjectStore` with that instead of a `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Try this (error checking omitted for clarity):

```
// Model
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

// Manually create a NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

// Add your persistent store to the coordinator
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Chapter4.sqlite"];
NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];
[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                              configuration:nil
                                                        URL:storeUrl
                                                    options:nil
                                                      error:nil];

// Init the RKManagedObjectStore with the coordinator
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:persistentStoreCoordinator];

// Let it create the NSManagedObjectContexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
```

Then, assuming you're working in the `mainQueueManagedObjectContext`, save it with:

```
[objectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks,  manually creating a NSPersistentStoreCoordinator fix my issue :RestKit 0.24 , iOS7.1 sdk8.2

Answer (score 1):

Since RestKit relies on CoreData, you need to save your ManagedObjectContext in order to persist the data. I'm not sure what version you are on, but I saved the data like this:

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore.managedObjectContextForCurrentThread save:nil];`

Put it inside `objectLoaderDidFinishLoading:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader`, and your objects should be saved.

Comment: Where is this objectLoaderDidFinishLoading: method?

Comment: Its a delegate-method to the object loader. You have to add it yourself

Comment: But I'm on a different version of restkit. It could be renamed, but the basics are: Once you are done loading all the objects. Save your MOC

Comment: In 0.20, delegates have disappeared in favor of a block approach. I'll try but it's weird, because I never had to do that before.